# admin-post.php form handling only working when logged in as admin

Tags: plugin-development

I built a custom plugin with a form (with form action=admin-post.php and a hidden input for action being the form handler function name) and form handler function, it works as expected on other sites but on this particular site it only works when logged in as admin.

If not logged in, or logged in as a regular user, form submission redirects to site front page. If logged in as admin the form handler function is fired properly.

Any ideas of how to fix?

Comment: The [admin-post.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.5.1/src/wp-admin/admin-post.php) file looks pretty straight-forward. Are you certain it's not a plugin or theme conflict? If you've ruled those out you may need to edit your question with some code.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I'm quite certain it's a plugin or theme conflict, possibly htaccess rules. I ended up doing a workaround by putting simple if post is set and post action = xyz then the form processing function. It seems like it would take hours and hours to take the site apart piece by piece to see where the issue is so I just took that shortcut.